# How to read a flash drive with the MAX3421E USB Host module built in an Arduino Mega 2560?

Tags: arduino, usb, atmega

I'm using an **Arduino Mega 2560** *(Iteaduino ADK v1.0d to be more specific, like the one shown below)*. It has a built-in **MAX3421E USB Host** module.

[image: Iteaduino ADK v1.0d]

**The main goal is: I want to read a text file from a flash drive plugged into its USB port.**

From the board's documentation, I know that the USB Host module uses the following Arduino pins:

```
7 - RST
50 - MISO
51 - MOSI
52 - SCK
```

I have tried using Kroll's library (https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) to do some mass storage testing and see what happens (i.e. https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/examples/USB_desc/USB_desc.ino), but nothing happened.

Also, I tried using the Greiman's library (https://github.com/greiman/UsbFat) with the DriveInfo example (https://github.com/greiman/UsbFat/blob/master/UsbFat/examples/UsbDriveInfo/UsbDriveInfo.ino) and it only returned:

```
UsbFat version: 20141220
FreeRam 7075
Error: initUSB failed
```

I think there might be the pins settings that are pointing to somewhere else, or I'm just using the wrong libraries for my board.

Does anybody know how to implement it to use the built-in USB port to read a flash drive?

Comment: This is not an [Arduino Mega 2560](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-mega-2560-rev3); it appears to be a third-party board.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to select **Arduino Mega ADK** as the board and the code uploads and runs.